# Can I remove a game from origin and then use the code on another origin account?

Tags: origin

Can I uninstall a game from origin and use the code on another account? I'm kind of new to Origin and I'm trying to play Crysis 3 online, but I can't because I don't have a email address connected to my account. I only have a parental account email, but I don't want that. I want my email to work when I log into the site and play multiplayer in games?

Answer (score 5):

You simply can't. Games that you buy on Steam or Origin are bound to your account forever.

Comment: but i have no email connected to my curret account so i cant play on multiplayer how do i solve that!?!?!?!?

Comment: @Oscar You may want to create a separate question for that, since it isn't really the same issue as this...

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact EA tech support, I'm afraid.